# ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x8007000B - VS2022 Winforms Project C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I tried this ways in two differents computers Win10:

- Registering MergeMod and Ole32(with Admin Privileges)
- Delete project setup and create again
- Reinstalling VS Installer Projects 2022
- Updating & Restarting the computer

It's the same, I have hours with this problem.

I create a project with VS2019 with a copy/paste of the files and works!
but with VS2022 failed
If anyone has the same situation with VS2022 and could solve, I'd love to hear about it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

0x8007000B is `ERROR_BAD_FORMAT` and most likely occurs when you are mismatching 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.  You're likely incorrectly registering a 32-bit DLL but trying to run it in a 64-bit exe (or the reverse situation could possibly be true too.)

If this is a plug-in to Visual Studio, please note that the Visual Studio IDE itself is now a 64-bit process, as of Visual Studio 2022, so your old 32-bit plug-ins may not work with the new 64-bit Visual Studio without being rebuilt to be compatible with a 64-bit host process.